Perl search and replace words in file
I am not sure how to search and replace word from Perl.
I have .txt that contains image file names in random order.
Animals.txt
There is an image Dog_Image_85.jpg
Cat has an image Cat_Image_front.jpg
Here is another image Dog_Image_61.jpg
Cat has another image Cat_Image_back.jpg
Next image Dog_Image_55.jpg
Next Image Cat_Image_side.jpg
Next Image Dog_Image_200.jpg

I only want to change the Dog image names to a counter so it goes:
There is an image Dog_Image_1.jpg
Cat has an image Cat_Image_front.jpg
Here is another image Dog_Image_2.jpg
Cat has another image Cat_Image_back.jpg
Next image Dog_Image_3.jpg
Next Image Cat_Image_side.jpg
Next Image Dog_Image_4.jpg

I have tried these but I get an error each time:
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w -I ../lib -I ./

use strict;

my $Animals = "Animals";

my $file = "$Animals.txt";

perl -pi -e 's/Dog_Image_.*.jpg/"Dog_Image_.++$i.jpg"/ge' $file;

This gives me an error: Can't use bareword perl.
I also tried with:
system('s/Dog_Image_.*.jpg/"Dog_Image_.++$i.jpg"/ge' $file);'

It still gives an error.

You have an unmatched " in the replacement string.

you can't use the perl statement inside another perl script, that's a shell command.

And similarly, you can't run Perl substitution as a shell command.

@barmar I missed the " when typing. Still gives me an error.

I don't think .++$i should be inside the quotes. It should be "Dog_Image_" . ++i . ".jpg"

It appears that you are trying to run a shell command, which would invoke perl to run a perl command-line program ("one-liner"), out of a Perl script.  This is of course possible but it is a bit of a convoluted back-on-itself acrobatics, usually quote hungry.  Why not do the job in that Perl script?
Here is one way, using a useful Path::Tiny library
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Path::Tiny;

my $file_name = ...
...

{
    my $dog_cnt = 0;
    path($file_name) -> edit( sub { 
        s/Dog_Image_\K([0-9]+)\.jpg/++$dog_cnt . '.jpg'/ge 
    });
}

The method edit runs the code in the callback on the content of the file that is slurped into $_, then overwrites the file.†  There is also edit_lines which applies the given code to one line at a time.  None of this behaves exactly like the -i from the command-line but that is not a drawback.
I put the code inside a {} block to localize that $dog_cnt counter.  Another option is to define that variable inside the callback, in particular if the surrounding code doesn't need the counter.
sub {
    my $dog_cnt = 0;
    s/Dog_Image_\K([0-9]+)\.jpg/++$dog_cnt . '.jpg'/ge 
}

Then the method edit_lines won't work for the code as it stands because the callback runs for each line so the counter is always redefined to zero.  Change as suitable.
Or, edit the file normally -- open, process line by line, overwrite the original in a way of your choosing,† after whatever checking you desire. It's not much code, just a few lines.  It beats running a complex shell command out of a script, by a country mile.  Not to mention  running a perl command-line program out of a Perl script.

†  The library doesn't state how it "overwrites" the file but in my tests the inode number changes, so it writes out a file with the changed content and then renames it over the original.
If the inode number needs to stay the same -- sometimes needed for tools used on the file -- then that can be done as follows.
Change the file by opening and processing it as usual and either writing the new version to a temporary file or keeping it in memory. Then open the original for writing -- what will truncate it -- and write that new content into it (from that temporary file or from memory, wherever you had it).  Now the original's content changed but the file'ss inode number didn't.  Remove the temporary file if there was one.

Here is one way to do it on the command line (this works in my shell):
perl -pi -e 's/Dog_Image_.*.jpg/"Dog_Image_" . ++$i . ".jpg"/e' Animals.txt

It overwrites the original file.
Quoting is crucial.  The key is to separate the fixed strings from the executed code on the replacement side of the substitution.  I do this with the . string concatenation operator.
There are many issues with your attempts.  You are mixing command-line Perl with Perl code that you would have in a file.

That worked for me in shell, but not in my perl script is there a specific way to format it to work within the script?

@TreyB Just use a while(<>) loop.  It's a little bit trickier to implement the -i, but you really, truly, genuinely do not want to do that.  Write your tools to act as simple filters and handle renames in the shell.

"Dog_Image_.++$i.jpg" isn't valid Perl code. "Dog_Image_" . ++$i . ".jpg" would be.
But you have numerous other errors. Fixed:
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

exec( "perl", "-i", "-pe" 's/Dog_Image_\K.*(?=\.jpg$)/++$i/se', "Animals.txt" );

It's simpler to switch to a shell script.
#!/usr/bin/sh

exec perl -i -pe's/Dog_Image_\K.*(?=\.jpg$)/++$i/se' Animals.txt


Here is a solution.  However I didnt modify the original file, instead I created a new file with the substitutions from the old file.  The perl file is animalImage.pl, the input file is animalImage.txt, and the output file is new_animalImage.txt
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $i=1;
while(<>){
    s/Dog_Image_\d*.jpg$/"Dog_Image_" . $i++ . ".jpg"/e;
    print;
}

Output looks like this
$perl animalImage.pl animalImage.txt

There is an image Dog_Image_1.jpg
Cat has an image Cat_Image_front.jpg
Here is another image Dog_Image_2.jpg
Cat has another image Cat_Image_back.jpg
Next image Dog_Image_3.jpg
Next Image Cat_Image_side.jpg
Next Image Dog_Image_4.jpg

After you are done testing, to create the new file you would want to run something like this
$perl animalImage.pl animalImage.txt > new_animalImage.txt

That is basically equivalent to the following one liner, but the one liner modifies the original file.  Modifying the original file is maybe not a good idea when you are testing.
perl -pi -e 's/Dog_Image_.*.jpg/"Dog_Image_" . ++$i . ".jpg"/e' animalImage.txt

The perl flags can be a little confusing when you see them for the first time.  Here is a post talking about what they mean and how they work.
Perl flags -pe, -pi, -p, -w, -d, -i, -t?

Yes, Google is notoriously difficult for looking up punctuation and,
unfortunately, Perl does seem to be mostly made up of punctuation
:-)
The command line switches are all detailed in perlrun (available
from the command line by calling perldoc perlrun). Going into the
options briefly, one-by-one:

-p: Places a printing loop around your command so that it acts on each line of standard input. Used mostly so Perl can beat the pants
off Awk in terms of power AND simplicity :-)
-n: Places a non-printing loop around your command.
-e: Allows you to provide the program as an argument rather than in a file. You don't want to have to create a script file for every
little Perl one-liner.
-i: Modifies your input file in-place (making a backup of the original). Handy to modify files without the {copy, delete-original, rename} process.
-w: Activates some warnings. Any good Perl coder will use this.
-d: Runs under the Perl debugger. For debugging your Perl code, obviously.
-t: Treats certain "tainted" (dubious) code as warnings (proper taint mode will error on this dubious code). Used to beef up Perl
security, especially when running code for other users, such as setuid
scripts or web stuff.



"….in terms of power AND simplicity" - power yes, but simplicity ? you mean the "simplicity" of perl failing to move on from Perl 5 ? or the "simplicity" of the perl engine commencing execution before it's even done parsing the input code just to have any amount of performance ? or the "simplicity" of perl having nearly a dozen different quotation operators ?

…. or the "simplicity" of file array being @F[ ] but sub-routine argument array is @_[ ], even though $_ references the input row by default.
